# Cardholder name not included when reading EMV card

Tags: nfc, apdu, contactless-smartcard, emv, tlv

I've successfully been able to retrieve the card number and expiry date from a contactless debit/credit card. However, the cardholder name is not being returned in the READ RECORD command response. Am I missing a something?

```
-   Select Application

#   IN_DATA_EXCHANGE
>>  D4 40 01 00 A4 04 00 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 00 
<<  D5 41 00 6F 43 84 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 A5 38 50 10 56 69 73 61 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 9F 38 18 9F 66 04 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F 1A 02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 BF 0C 08 9F 5A 05 31 08 26 08 26 90 00

-   Read the card

#   IN_DATA_EXCHANGE
>>  D4 40 01 00 B2 01 0C 00 
<<  D5 41 00 70 12 57 10 XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX D1 50 52 01 00 00 00 01 90 00
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not uncommon for an EMV payment card to not reveal the cardholder name over the contactless interface. In fact, all major brands have introduced this as a privacy feature. On many cards the cardholder name field (tag `5F20`) is present but filled with a string like " /" to indicate that the cardholder name is not to be revealed. At least for Visa cards (like the one you have above) the cardholder name field is not mandatory (and if its not present, its value should be assumed as " /"). You might want to also check other records/files on the card. Some cards also provide this field in response to the GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command only.

Comment: thanks for the help. I have tried reading the other files for all the cards I have (Visa and Mastercard) but 5F20 is not present on all 3. Do I need to do GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command beforehand?

Comment: No, GPO should not be necessary to retrieve static card data.

Comment: I managed to get the cardholders name off another card here in the UK.

Comment: @ritch Over the contactless interface? Could you reveal the brand and the issuance date?

Comment: @ritch Whether the card contains tag 5F20 It will depend how and when the card was pursered.  Modern cards should not return the tag, old or non-compliant ones may.

Comment: For me on some visa credit cards, card number (5A) is null. is there is a way to request 5A?